# Algorithm for searching landscape of 2D "room" for obstacles

Tags: algorithm

I've done the usual google searching for an algorithm that describes this problem, but without much luck. The problem is as follows:

You're dropped off at a random point in a room, and expected to traverse the room and find all of the obstacles that lay within the room, marking them, and then moving on to find other obstacles. You can move in the 4 cardinal directions, but you can sense the environment around you in 8 directions (N, S, W, E, NW, SW, SE, NE). You also cannot remember locations you have visited previously.

Does anyone know the name of that problem or an algorithm to help solve it? Thanks!

An example of the room might look something like this:

```
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
U                   U
U                   U
U                   U
U       UUUUU       U
U       U   U       U
U       UUUUU       U
U                   U
U    UUUUUU         U
U    U    U         U
U    UUU  U         U
U      U  U         U
U    UUU  U         U
U    U    U         U
U    UUUUUU         U
U                   U    
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
```

Comment: Are the obstacles "walls" or "points"?

Comment: They are walls. I may not have been clear enough. I will put an example in the original questions!

Comment: _"You also cannot remember locations you have visited previously."_ What is the difference between "marking" and "remembering" a location?

Comment: @Kevin O(n) vs O(k) space? (n number of cells, k number of obstacles), if `k<<n` - it makes sense.